# JAXB 2 spring-ws 2.0.3.RELEASE SOAP Services Tutorial Link/Advice Request

Tags: xml, spring, jaxb, spring-ws

I am trying to use JAXB 2 and spring-ws 2.0.3 to make a SOAP service on glassfish 3.

I am having some problems with the xml file configurations because there is a ton of information (tutorials, examples) about getting older versions of these packages running but not much on the newer versions.

I have succesfully gotten client/server programs working through the httpInvokerProxy remoting service, but the amount of configuration required in these files is substantially more.

Essentially I used the xjc maven tool to create java classes out of my xml schema and the spring-ws annotations `@PayloadRoot`, `@EndPoint`, and `@ResponsePayload` to mark the methods in my endpoint java class. I am just trying to be sure that my wsdl file is available at the correct URL and that soap requests are being accepted and the responses delivered.

If someone could recommend a good place to get this information or have the heart to look through my 3 xml files I would be very greatful. Otherwise, here is the error I am getting when going to the root servlet directory after uploading the war file.

> org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class     [org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.core.convert.converter.ConverterRegistry.addConverter(Ljava/lang/Class;Ljava/lang/Class;Lorg/springframework/core/convert/converter/Converter

My xml files are as follows:

`web.xml`

```
    <web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee
             http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd"
         version="2.4">

    <display-name>Licensing SOAP Service</display-name>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>licensingSOAPService</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.ws.transport.http.MessageDispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>licensingSOAPService</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

`licensingSOAPService-servlet.xml`

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">

    <import resource-"/applicationContext.xml"/>

    <bean id = "licensingSOAPService" class="mypackage.soap.LicensingSOAPService">
    </bean>

    <bean class="org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.mapping.PayloadRootAnnotationMethodEndpointMapping">
        <description>An endpoint mapping strategy that looks for @Endpoint and @PayloadRoot annotations.</description>
    </bean>

    <bean class="org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.adapter.MarshallingMethodEndpointAdapter">
        <description>Enables the MessageDispatchServlet to invoke methods requiring OXM marshalling.</description>
        <constructor-arg ref="marshaller"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="marshaller" class="org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller"
          p:contextPath="mypackage.schemas" />


    <bean id = "licensingWSDL" class ="org.springframework.ws.wsdl.wsdl11.DefaultWsdl11Definition">
        <property name = "schema" ref = "schema">
        <property name = "portTypeName" value = "licenseResource"/>
        <property name = "locationUri" value ="/licensing/schema/" />
        <property name = "targetNamespace" value = "mypackage/schemas" />
    </bean>

    <bean id ="schema" class ="org.springframework.xml.xsd.SimpleXsdSchema">
        <property name ="xsd" value = "/licenseSchema.xsd"/>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

`applicationContext.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:sws="http://www.springframework.org/schema/web-services"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/web-services
http://www.springframework.org/schema/web-services/web-services-2.0.xsd">

<sws:annotation-driven />

<context:component-scan base-package="mypackagel.licensing"/>  
</beans>
```

Does anybody see anything blatantly wrong with these?

EDIT:

Wanted to include dependency part of my pom.xml as it was pointed out (correctly so) that I have both spring 3.1 AND spring 3.5 jars in my war file.

```
<repositories>
        <repository> 
            <id>com.springsource.repository.bundles.release</id> 
            <name>SpringSource Enterprise Bundle Repository - SpringSource Bundle Releases</name> 
            <url>http://repository.springsource.com/maven/bundles/release</url> 
        </repository>
        <repository>
          <id>maven2-repository.dev.java.net</id>
          <name>Java.net Repository for Maven</name>
          <url>http://download.java.net/maven/2/</url>
          <layout>default</layout>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>  
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj</groupId>  
            <artifactId>saaj-impl</artifactId>  
            <version>1.3</version>  
            <scope>runtime</scope>  
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.ws</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-ws-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>  
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>  
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>  
            <version>2.0</version>  
        </dependency>  
        <dependency>  
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>  
            <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>  
            <version>2.0.3</version>  
        </dependency>  
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <finalName>LicensingSOAPService</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jaxb2-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generate</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The exception message refers to the method

```
ConverterRegistry.addConverter(Class, Class, Converter)
```

This method was only introduced in Spring 3.1 (see [javadoc](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/convert/converter/ConverterRegistry.html#addConverter%28java.lang.Class,%20java.lang.Class,%20org.springframework.core.convert.converter.Converter%29)), so something in your setup is assuming the presence of Spring 3.1, but you seem to be running 3.0.

You need to upgrade Spring to 3.1

Comment: I already using Spring 3.1, but I will check into whether or not 3.1 is not compatible with spring-ws at the version I am using. Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: @thatidiotguy: Make sure you don't have both 3.0 and 3.1 in your classpath at the same time, too.

Comment: Hi skaffman, yes it turns out this is indeed the problem, I have 3.0.5 and 3.1 spring packages in my war. But my pom clearly says 3.1.0, this must mean that some other dependency is requesting the older version correct? If so is there a quick way to discover what this is? I mean I do not really have anything that seems like it would depend on spring packages. Just in case I have put the dependency part of my pom back in the question. Thanks.

Comment: @thatidiotguy: That's a maven question.  Not really my area of expertise.  Try asking a new question.

Comment: Very true, thanks for the help, and hopefully after solving classpath issue, this main issue will be resolved. Would +1 you guys if I could.

Comment: @thatidiotguy: You can +1.  Use the voting buttons, and/or the tick next to the answer.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6895/discussion-between-thatidiotguy-and-skaffman)